# Bug with ' * ' as argument

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm a beginner and try to learn some c. I make a program to learn the pointer on functions in with I give 3 arguments to the program at launch: an int, an operator and another int.
Everything works fine with %, -, +, and /. But for * I have a very weird bug. After a lot of write() everywhere to find where it starts to bug, I find that it is at the very beginning: when I display argv[2][0], it display the good char for everything exept for the * where it shows "Makefile"... 
I really don't understand this issue and I don't find anything related to * and arguments bugs. I don't even bug on the pointers or other thing since it's from the start.

Here is the start of the code so you can see:

```
#include"header.h"

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_putstr(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        ft_putchar(str[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char    operator;

    ft_putchar(argv[2]); //here it shows "Makefile"...
```

And some output: ( first the char representation, then the number of chars, then another time the char representation but further away in the code and then the result, * is always 0 because it just quit the main after not following any conditions next)

```
➜  exercice05 ./ft_op 100 / 5
/1/20
➜  exercice05 ./ft_op 100 + 5
+1+105
➜  exercice05 ./ft_op 100 - 5
-1-95
➜  exercice05 ./ft_op 100 % 5
%1%0
➜  exercice05 ./ft_op 100 * 5
Makefile80
```

The bug is so strange I can only imagine it's something obvious but I'm clueless right now to find it. I do have a Makefile in my dir but I really don't see where would be the problem.
I'm on macOS Catalina, tried on bash and zsh, same result.
Just in case here is the makefile :

```
TARGET = ft_op
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:.c =.o)
FLAG = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CC = gcc

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(FLAG) $^  -o $@

.PHONY: clean fclean

clean:
    rm -f *.o
fclean: clean
    rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Thank you

Comment: Try putting in quotes. The OS is probably treating it like a wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C program isn't getting `*` as an argument, because your shell is expanding it first. You need to use it as `'*'` or `\*` when you call your program: `exercice05 ./ft_op 100 '*' 5` or `exercice05 ./ft_op 100 \* 5`

Compare the outputs of `echo *`, `echo '*'` and `echo \*` to make it more clear.

Comment: When compiling on Windows with mingw, you could turn off globbing (see https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1999-11/msg00052.html) by compiling like this: `gcc ft_op.c C:\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\CRT_noglob.o`